# GCC built from source in different location is incorrectly using same shared libs as native GCC

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries

I'm a student doing research involving extending the TM capabilities of gcc. My goal is to make changes to gcc source, build gcc from the modified source, and, use the new executable the same way I'd use my distro's vanilla gcc.

**I built and installed gcc in a different location** (not `/usr/bin/gcc`), specifically because the modified gcc will be unstable, and because our project goal is to compare transactional programs compiled with the two different versions.

Our changes to gcc source impact both `/gcc` and `/libitm`. This means we are making a change to libitm.so, one of the shared libraries that get built.

My expectation:

- when compiling `myprogram.cpp` with `/usr/bin/g++`, the version of libitm.so that will get linked should be the one that came with my distro;
- when compiling it with `~/project/install-dir/bin/g++`, the version of libitm.so that will get linked should be the one that just got built when I built my modified gcc.

But in reality it seems **both native gcc and mine are using the same libitm**, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libitm.so.1`.

I only have a rough grasp of gcc internals as they apply to our project, but this is my understanding:

- Our changes tell one compiler pass to conditionally insert our own "function builtin" instead of one it would normally use, and this is / becomes a "symbol" which needs to link to libitm.
- When I use the new gcc to compile my program, that pass detects those conditions and successfully inserts the symbol, but then at runtime my program gives a "relocation error" indicating the symbol is not defined in the file it is searching in: `./test: relocation error: ./test: symbol _ITM_S1RU4, version LIBITM_1.0 not defined in file libitm.so.1 with link time reference`
- `readelf` shows me that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libitm.so.1` does not contain our new symbols while `~/project/install-dir/lib64/libitm.so.1` does; if I re-run my program after simply copying the latter libitm over the former (backing it up first, of course), it does not produce the relocation error anymore. But naturally this is not a permanent solution.

So **I want the gcc I built to use the shared libs that were built along with it when linking.** And I don't want to have to tell it where they are every time - my feeling is that it should know where to look for them since I deliberately built it somewhere else to behave differently.

This sounds like the kind of problem any amateur gcc developer would have when trying to make a dev environment and still be able to use both versions of gcc, but I had difficulty finding similar questions. I am thinking this is a matter of lacking certain config options when I configure gcc before building it. What is the right configuration to do this?

My small understanding of [the instructions for building and installing gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) led me to do the following:

```
cd ~/project/
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
../source-dir/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/home/myusername/project/install-dir
make -j2
make install
```

I only have those config options because they seemed like the ones closest related to "only building the parts I need" and "not overwriting native gcc", but I could be wrong. After the initial config step I just re-run `make -j2` and `make install` every time I change the code. All these steps do complete without errors, and they produce the `~/project/install-dir/bin/` folder, containing the `gcc` and `g++` which behave as described.

I use `~/project/install-dir/bin/g++ -fgnu-tm -o myprogram myprogram.cpp` to compile a transactional program, possibly with other options for programs with threads.

(I am using Xubuntu 16.04.3 (64 bit), within VirtualBox on Windows. The installed `/usr/bin/gcc` is version 5.4.0. Our source at `~/project/source-dir/` is a modified version of 5.3.0.)

Comment: How did you tell the linker to use `~/project/install-dir/lib64/libitm.so.1`?

Comment: @muru I didn't explicitly tell the linker _anything,_ and part of my problem/question is that it is _not_ using that file (and I want it to do so automatically). I built gcc as described, and used it to compile a test program as described. Then when the relocation error told me it couldn't find the symbol, I basically used `find / -name "libitm*"` to figure out where any `libitm.so` files were (the ones in `/usr/lib` came with the distro; the ones in `~/project/install-dir/` came from my build).

Comment: the linker will not automagically pick up libraries. You'd have to use the `-L` option, or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or add configuration for `ldconfig` informing it about that directory before the linker will use it.

Comment: @muru Isn't the linker part of the gcc I just built? You're saying it does not automatically search certain relative paths close to where it was installed, it just uses that environment variable or the `-L` option or `ldconfig`? I'll look into this more.

Comment: Apologies, I conflated the linker and the loader. The linker will have to be told the location via the `-L` flag to gcc when compiling. The runtime error would be from the loader, which will have to be told the library location with `ldconfig` or the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variableduring runtime, unless you statically linked that particularly library.

Comment: libitm.so is not a part of gcc. The linker will not magically select a different version of libitm.so just because it happens to be installed under the same user directory as the compiler you are using. If you do want this to happen you need to modify gcc such that it tels the linker to use a modified library search path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re running into build- versus run-time linking differences. When you build with `-fgnu-tm`, the compiler knows where the library it needs is found, and it tells the linker where to find it; you can see this by adding `-v` to your `g++` command. However when you run the resulting program, the dynamic linker doesn’t know it should look somewhere special for the ITM library, so it uses the default library in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Things get even more confusing with ITM on Ubuntu because the library is installed system-wide, but the link script is installed in a GCC-private directory. This doesn’t happen with the default GCC build, so your own GCC build doesn’t do this, and you’ll see `libitm.so` in `~/project/install-dir/lib64`.

To fix this at run-time, you need to tell the dynamic linker where to find the right library. You can do this either by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (to `/home/.../project/install-dir/lib64`), or by storing the path in the binary using `-Wl,-rpath=/home/.../project/install-dir/lib64` when you build it.